# How to optimize HAProxy running in docker

Tags: docker, kernel, haproxy

I'm doing app migration from virtual machine to container.
At last, I decide using HAProxy to do load balancing thing in order to delivery the web & API applications.
Bridge mode has been used, as you know, docker use iptables to NAT containers' traffic, so I'm considering the performance of it.
Cause the infrastructure of this app that I'm operating on, has pressure. The peak load more than 1000 qps.
Any suggestions for optimizing HAProxy 、kernel networking properties in host 、 in container and so on.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad to be answered in this format. What have you considered so far? Generally you don't want to be manually changing iptables.

Comment: Container use the Kernel of the host.

Comment: I suggest you go with the docker swarm mode load balancing. it has the best performance since it is done natively in docker